# Assertions or Annotations for thread correctness

Tags: java, multithreading, annotations, assertions

I am coding as part of a project which uses multithreading and I'm trying to find ways to detect thread mistakes in my code.
Are there some existing tools I could use to help me do this?

For example-
an assert that my method is being called by the correct thread
or
some kind of static checking with annotations, similar to @Nullable and @NotNull, to detect when my code calls a method from the wrong thread.

Although the project is multithreaded, there is almost no synchronisation required because the different threads don't access the same objects, they have their own instances.
Broadly speaking, there are four threads running at once

- Server thread = maintains the state of the game for one or more
  clients
- Client thread = processes user input, maintains a local
  copy/cache of server data for rendering
- NetworkMessage thread =    processes incoming/outgoing messages
  between server and client
- Render thread = processes the local data into rendering information for the
  graphics card

The classes are sometimes intended for only one of the threads (for example user input polling is client-only), sometimes they are for multiple threads (eg the calculated movement of a projectile uses the same code on both client and server simultaneously to reduce perceived lag).  Several times I've called a method from the wrong thread, leading to subtle and unrepeatable bugs and very nearly serious monitor screen damage (from my fist)

What I have thought of so far is something like this:

```
public void myMethodThatAssumesClientThreadOnly() {
  assert checkThread(CLIENT);
  // can now happily call other client-thread code without fear 
}
```

but I would prefer something with static checking similar to @Nullable

eg

```
@Thread(CLIENT)
void myClientMethod() {
  //client-only stuff here
}

@Thread(SERVER)
void myServerMethod() {
  //server-only stuff here
}

@Thread(CLIENT + SERVER)
void myClientAndMethod() {
  myClientMethod();  // error- server thread might call client method 
}
```

Unfortunately, being an annotation noob, I have no clue whether this is easy or actually very hard.

Any pointers?  I can't imagine I'm the first one to look for something like this.

TGG

Comment: The android annotation project has some support for this- you can Mark functions as meeting to be on the ui thread or not on it. I'm not a fan of most of the library, but you should be able to look at how they do it and possibly expand on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Checker Framework](http://CheckerFramework.org/) enables the creation of compile-time static checkers that verify program correctness.  Its [GUI Effect Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#guieffect-checker) is similar to what you want.  Here is an abridged excerpt from [its manual](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#guieffect-checker):

> One of the most prevalent GUI-related bugs is invalid UI update or invalid thread access: accessing the UI directly from a background thread.
>
> If a background thread accesses a UI element such as a JPanel (by calling a JPanel method or reading/writing a field of JPanel), the GUI framework raises an exception that terminates the program.
>
> It is difficult for a programmer to remember which methods may be called on which thread(s). The GUI Effect Checker solves this problem. The programmer annotates each method to indicate whether:
>
> - It accesses no UI elements (and may run on any thread).
> - It may access UI elements (and must run on the UI thread).
>
> The GUI Effect Checker statically enforces that UI methods are only called from the correct thread.

The GUI Effect Checker is tuned to detect and prevent GUI threading errors, whereas you are concerned about client-server threading errors.  However, the principles are the same and you should be able to adapt the GUI Effect Checker to your needs with relatively few changes.

There is a [paper](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/pubs/gui-thread-ecoop2013-abstract.html) that discusses case studies using the GUI Effect Checker.

An alternative is to adapt a [bug finder](https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/pubs/gui-thread-issta2012-abstract.html) for finding errors in multithreaded applications.  Unlike the GUI Effect Checker, it does not give a *guarantee* that there are no threading bugs.  However, it is effective in practice, and it does not require you to write any annotations in your program.

Finally, the Checker Framework also contains a [Lock Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#lock-checker) that ensures correct synchronization.  That helps to prevent concurrency errors, though it's orthogonal to your chief concerns about thread safety.

Answer (score 1):

This will assert that method `foobar()` is called by the correct thread...

```
SomeType foobar(...) {
    assert(Thread.currentThread() == theCorrectThread);
    ...
}
```

...If, somewhere in your code prior to the first `foobar()` call you have set

```
Thread theCorrectThread = new Thread(...);
```

---

> but I would prefer something with static checking similar to @Nullable

I know very little about annotations myself.  I know that they can be used to attach meta-information to compiled classes, and I know that the program can obtain that information at run-time by calling methods of the `Class` object, but if there's any way an annotation can define *compile-time* behavior, that's beyond my ken.

Probably a moot point anyway.  When the compiler is processing a .java file, there is no way for it to tell what thread or threads might possibly execute the code that it contains.

Comment: Annotations can define compile time behvaior-  you can read annotations at compile time via reflection.

Comment: @GabeSechan, well that's interesting, but how can I write Java code that gets executed at compile time?  That would be very interesting, but I've never seen any hint that it can be done.

Comment: I mistyped, I meant runtime. But you can also use annotations at compile time, it's a pre compile step generating code that's then compiled. It's a fairly common technique.